# Windows 10 clean boot after wiping disk clean

Tags: windows-10, boot, filesystems, fixmbr

I recently updated win 10 OS on my laptop which resulted in a crash. I tried several ways to solve it but in the end, i ended up wiping the entire disk clean. I used a live ubuntu cd to merge all partitions into one ntfs (left out the efi partition). But when I try to install win10 from a live usb, the hard disk partition isn't visible during installation to choose the volume from. I've been trying to find a solution for this problem since 2 days. Anyone please tell me what could be causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: Default "partition layout for UEFI-based computer is: a system partition, an MSR, a Windows partition, and a recovery tools partition." See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-does-not-need-efi-and-msr-partition/c8dfde81-e94f-4634-bdc4-8a4300bf589b Se also https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/missing-efi-partition-windows-10.html

Comment: If I remove the hard disk from laptop, connnect it externally to another computer, quick format it and connect it back to my laptop, can I install windows 10 directly on it?

Comment: No. Again, see https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/missing-efi-partition-windows-10.html to recreate EFI part. You can also create an EFI partition using the Ubuntu 18.04 installation. https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-on-uefi-and-legacy-bios-system.html